# Self in Class Method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am reading some Objective-C code in a well-maintained GitHub repo. https://github.com/soffes/sskeychain/blob/master/SSKeychain.m

I came across some weird lines (at least weird to my eyes).

```
+ (NSArray *)allAccounts {
    return [self accountsForService:nil error:nil];
}
```

I was taught that **self** refers to the instance itself in an instance method. So what does **self** mean here, in a class method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside class methods, `self` refers to the object representing the corresponding `Class`:

```
+ (NSArray *)allAccounts {
    NSLog("%@", [self description]); // Will print the name of the class
    return [self accountsForService:nil error:nil];
}
```

This is the same object that you get in an instance method when you call `[self class]`.

It is useful if you would like to call methods on the `class` polymorphically. For example, you can call `[[self alloc] init]` to create a new instance of the class on which the call is performed.

Comment: I'd avoid using the word 'instance' in your first sentence. It's a bit confusing and misleading.

Comment: @rmaddy I guess you're right, one could potentially misinterpret the word "instance" in this context.